# How to get a Google Profiles name?

Tags: google, google-plus, profile

I already have a Google+ profile with this ugly long URL:

```
https://plus.google.com/106542087505398120198/
```

I recently discovered in [this LifeHacker article](http://lifehacker.com/5566470/how-to-set-up-openid-on-your-own-domain) that the author has a much shorter Google Profiles name (here: `http://www.google.com/profiles/ginatrapani`).

I tried if I already had such a profile by using my Google nickname and the first part of my Gmail address as suffix but this didn't work.

I checked all my Account settings but I can't find out where to apply or change for such a name. If I go to http://www.google.com/profiles it leads me straight to my Google+ account.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like under an older Google Profiles system (such as Buzz) it was possible to have a pretty URL like you've found above. Google axed it as a default however, in part because it effectively exposed users' username / email addresses.

The best article I could find on the topic was [this blog post](http://knowem.com/blog/2012/06/01/you-may-or-may-not-already-have-a-google-vanity-url/), which mentions:

> if you had selected a vanity URL for your old Google Profile those have been grandfathered in to point to your current Google+ profile.

They may be coming at some stage, in terms of anything from Google itself is [this line](http://productforums.google.com/d/topic/pages-discuss/teuGGtMdT74) in the product forum in March:

> The team has actually decided to take another look at vanity URLs
>   based on user feedback and will be talking about whether or how to
>   proceed - rest assured that they have not been ruled out. Stay tuned
>   for updates.

In the mean time there are a bunch of URL shortening services operating you could use, or if you have your own domain you can [point that](http://donaldjenkins.com/2011/07/how-to-set-up-a-yourdomain-com-redirect-in-one-htaccess-line/) to your profile.

Comment: http://gplus.to is one such URL-shortening service specifically for "prettifying" G+ profile URLs. There are several others.